# Добавление таблиц в SQL DB

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio-2015

Создал файл баз данных sql UserStore.mdf. В обозревателе серверов VS15 не могу добавить таблицу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же при открытие в SQL Management studio не могу открыть этот файл БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как добавить таблицу в этот файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашёл, установил [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027) и могу создавать таблицы прямо в студии